# Prolog - like gensym, but for variables

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to generate some rules in runtime with the help of `dynamic/1` and `assert/1` rules.

Is there a way to generate variables to be used in that rules, just like `gensym` but for generating variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use either functor/3 or length/2. Both can create variables you can access subsequently by index, using respectively arg/3 or nth1/3.

For instance

```
?- functor(T, $, 5), arg(3, T, some_value).
T = $(_G1070, _G1071, some_value, _G1073, _G1074).
```

or

```
?- length(T, 5), nth1(3, T, other_value).
T = [_G1070, _G1073, other_value, _G1079, _G1082].
```

Comment: Would `copy_term/2` also be appropriate? I believe it also generates variables.